# <IonToast> should be shown when there's no network connection, but it's not

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I'm working on an `Ionic React Project` running on top of `Capacitor` and I need to show a Toast message `<IonToast>`, everytime there's **no internet connection**. To get network and connectivity information, I'm using `Network Capacitor Plugin`: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/network
I'm using Context hook for using props everywhere in the app.

In **MyContext.tsx** I have declared the necessary constants as following:

```
const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [toastMessage, setToastMessage] = useState("");
```

In **HomePage.tsx**:

```
import {
  IonContent,
  IonPage,
  IonButton,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonAlert,
  IonToast,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Network } from "@capacitor/network";

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    firstName,
    setFirstName,
    showToast,
    setShowToast,
    toastMessage,
    setToastMessage,
  } = React.useContext(MyContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  //Check internet connection status
  useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    const logCurrentNetworkStatus = async () => {
      const status = await Network.getStatus();
      if (mounted.current) {
        if (status.connected) {
          setShowToast(false);
        } else {
          setShowToast(true);
          setToastMessage("No internet connection");
        }
      }
    };
    return () => {
      logCurrentNetworkStatus();
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  console.log("showToast is " + showToast);
  console.log("Toast message is " + toastMessage);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonPage className="ion-page" id="main-content">
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">
          <IonGrid>
            <IonRow>
              <IonCol>
                <IonToast
                  isOpen={showToast}
                  onDidDismiss={() => setShowToast(false)}
                  message={toastMessage}
                  position="top"
                  buttons={["Ok"]}
                />
              </IonCol>
            </IonRow>

                  <h5 className="text-center">Welcome to home page</h5>
                
          </IonGrid>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

My issue is: Toast message is not showing at all. I have logged `showToast` and its value is always **false**, even when I have no internet connection in my Android emulator (showToast should be set to true).

In console, I can see the result of `Network.getStatus`:

```
result Network.getStatus
connected: false
```

It seems like useEffect() is not executed at all. I added some console.log inside useEffect() and none of them was shown in console when HomePage was rendered.
Do you have any idea why?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the network check into MyContext.tsx and use the listener provided by the API

```
const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [toastMessage, setToastMessage] = useState("");


Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', status => {
  console.log('Network status changed', status);
  status.connected ?  setShowToast(true) :   setShowToast(false)
});
```

this way you can set the state appropriate independent of the specific page, which in this example is the home page.

Comment: thank you, I'm changing it right now. What about `<IonToast>`? Should I put it in every page of my app?